# Can you force network manager to use localhost for new wifi networks?

Tags: network-manager

When connecting to a new WIFI network (via `nm-applet`) is there a way to force NetworkManager to default to using localhost as DNS server instead of defaulting to DHCP's DNS?

I know how to change it manually but I was wondering if there was a way to save on the work it takes to change each wifi network to use 127.0.0.1 as DNS and DHCP for address only.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Through the use of **dnsmasq** and **systemd-resolved**, your system already uses localhost (127.0.0.x) for DNS lookups and caching.

In terminal, type `cat /etc/resolv.conf` (*don't manually edit this file*) and you'll see either 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.0.53, depending on whether **dnsmasq** or **systemd-resolved** is managing the DNS. They'll use local cache first, and then probably go out to your router (192.168.x.1) for lookups. Specific DNS servers can be specified in the local computer's network script, or in the router setup. In a perfect world, you shouldn't probably be running both **dnsmasq** and **systemd-resolved** at the same time.

To check your system... in terminal...

```
ps auxc | grep -i dns

ps auxc | grep -i resolv
```

Comment: `systemd-resolved` is in charge of handling DNS requests however it should forward the requests based on NetworkManager settings and NetworkManager will set the default DNS servers for newly created connections based on information coming from DHCP.  Run `systemd-resolve --status device` example: `systemd-resolve --status enp3s0` to see where will be DNS requested forwarded by systemd-resoved.

Comment: @Ravexina that is correct, only if `systemd-resolved` is running solo, and if specific DNS servers have not been set in the network script (*Wired Connection, etc.*) If `dnsmasq` is also installed and running, it gets a little more complicated.

Comment: I am using unbound so i can do DNS over TLS, so am not using **dnsmasq** or **systemd-resolv**

Answer (score 0):

As you say that you are using unbound, it sounds like you want NetworkManager not to write /etc/resolv.conf at all. Configure `main.dns=none` or `main.rc-manager=unmanaged` in NetworkManager.conf. See `man NetworkManager.conf` for details.